# Linq with multiple foreach inserting items to table

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have list of ids like this below

```
       List<int> ids = new List<int>();
```

and then i have list of lengths which is also integers like this below..

```
       List<int> lengths = new List<int>();
```

now i need to insert into table using linq query with the data format like this  below

```
         ID  length
          1    1
          1    2
          1    3
          2    1
          2    2
          2    3
```

for that i am doing like this

```
     foreach (var item in ids)
     {
             foreach (var item in lengths)
             {

              }

       }
```

With the above way i am not able insert the multiple id's in the table .. I am hoping there should be better way to do this.. 
Could any one please suggest any ideas on this one that would be very grateful to me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you consider better? You have to (e.g. in your example) do 6 inserts somehow, a nest loop is easiest.

Comment: If your table is configured to use `id` as a primary key, it doesn't matter how you structure your C# code, you simply cannot insert both (1,1) and (1,2) into the same table. Can you clarify what kind of exception/error you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to project these 2 lists to a flattened list with *LINQ*, you could use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
// projecting to an anonymous type 

var results = ids.SelectMany(id => lengths.Select(length => new {id, length }));

// or projecting to a value tuple

var results = ids.SelectMany(id => lengths.Select(length => (id, length)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a single loop, you can loop over the final result length and compute the indexes into each `List`:

```
var idsCount = ids.Count;
var lengthsCount = lengths.Count;
var totalCount = idsCount * lengthsCount;
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < totalCount; ++j1) {
    var id = ids[j1 / lengthsCount];
    var length = lengths[j1 % lengthsCount];
    new { id, length }.Dump();
    // insert id,length
}
```